# GCal Python: Create new event without any time (only date)?

Tags: python, google-calendar-api

When I normally use Google Calendar, I can click above the timeline (in the space right below each date) where I can set reminders and events with no time that just show up at the very top. Is there a way to add events with no time (only day) like that in python? I tried just having a date with no time as the `dateTime` value, but I get an error about the time range being empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `date` property of [events.insert](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/insert) instead of `dateTime`.

> - **end.date**: *date*
> - The date, in the format "yyyy-mm-dd", if this is an all-day event.
> - **start.date**: *date*
> - The date, in the format "yyyy-mm-dd", if this is an all-day event.

Whereas the `dateTime` property is described as:

> The time, as a combined date-time value (formatted according to
> [RFC3339](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3339)). A time zone offset is required unless a time zone is
> explicitly specified in timeZone.